# Phone won't turn on - Samsung Galaxy S II

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

My Galaxy S2 won't turn on. It just keeps flashing the Samsung Galaxy S2 screen.

I turned it off, then held the power button and the down volume button and a screen popped up with the green android. It says "downloading do not turn off target". How long does this take to download?

Comment: Ha ha..it just a download mode..it wont download anything(Ofcourse..yes it shows downloading but progressing bar will work when you flash the firware/Os using ODIN). Just press and hold power button or remove the battery and try restarting it. I hope you are using the stock Rom provided by samsung. If you dont want any data press Up + Home + Power and do a wipe and try.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution: http://www.widefide.com/mobile/samsung-galaxy-sii-not-booting-heres-the-solution

It was written by me years ago and helped a few who had their S2 bricked.
Follow in order: First soft reset, then hard reset and if it doesn't reboot even afterwards, move on to the third (advanced) step.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you are booting the phone into download mode. So technically your phone is turning on just fine but you are not doing it in the way that boots android.

Instead just press and hold *only* the power button until you see some flashing or the boot logo appears.

Download mode is like samsungs sort of equivalent to fastboot. It will simply sit there indefinitely until *you* send it something manually.

If you want to enter recovery, it's <kbd>power</kbd> + <kbd>volume up</kbd> instead.

If you can't actually boot android using the normal power button only boot, then you'll need to fix your install. You're in the best position if you already have a custom recovery flashed. If not, you'll have to do a more complete restore of the stock OS.

Answer (score 0):

SoftBricked!!!!! You need to re-install everything. Checkout How to [restore Samsung Galaxy S2](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=restoring%20samsung%20galaxy%20s2%20using%20odin) . Go for XDA one